# Leaky waveguide - calculating the frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, waveguide

> The figure shows a waveguide with a square cross-section. The length of the side of the cross-section is $a = 3.5$ .  A TE wave with a frequency f propagates in the waveguide in the positive direction of the Z axis. In the upper wall of the waveguide, two small holes were made that were distant from each other by $L = 13.8$ - as shown in the figure. Calculate the frequency for which constructive interference at point P occurs for the angle $θ = 90^o$. Assume that the speed of light in a vacuum is $c_0 = 3*10^8 $ .
>
> [image: Leaky waveguide]

So, I have this example to do, and I have a big problem with it, because all the formulas for waveguides are not so useful (yup, I tried patterns for $fc$, or even tried some of the waveguide online calculators but they are useless for this problem). I don't know any patterns that includes theta angle, and I don't know what to do when there are holes on top of the waveguide (mostly because we don't have lectures in this subject - we only have quizes, and sadly this is our only form of learning). Do you have any idea how to calculate this frequency?

Comment: hint: if you knew the frequency would you know how to calculate the propagating wavelength *in the waveguide* of the $TE_{10}$ mode?

Comment: I did some research and found this formoula, [is it correct](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/images2/waveguide-cutoff-wavelength-round-equation.gif)?

Comment: @hyportnex but I don't know if this will help me :(

Comment: That is the wrong formula, your problem is about a rectangular waveguide not circular waveguide, and it is not even the *propagating* wavelength of the wave. Anyhow, this is a homework problem and I have given you a hint how to solve it. This is not a site to give out solutions but if you have a specific question about *physics* then you will get more help here.

Comment: @hyportnex Yup, that's true, this is not a site for homework solutions. The only thing I wanted to know was an formula, because as I said, we need to learn by yourself, we don't have lectures, we don't have exercises we have only a platform where we need to solve this quizzes.

[Maybe this formula is correct](http://d2xunoxnk3vwmv.cloudfront.net/uploads/lambda-guide.jpg)

[And here is the source](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/waveguide-mathematics)

Comment: Now you have the right formula to solve your homework, but you still have to work on it and if you have questions on principles and/or concepts you will get help here.

Comment: @hyportnex Thank you! I transformed this formula on paper and then typed it to the wolfram, the result is perfectly correct (except its not in Giga, maybe I need to change my a and b, but do you know on what SI unit?).

[This is my result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(c+sqrt(4+a%5E2+%2B+l%5E2))%2F(2+a+l)+let+c%3D3*10%5E8+let+a%3D3.5+let+l%3D13.8)

Comment: Oh, and do you know how to transform this formula on Wolfram? I tried to do it on so many ways, and failed, so I did it on a paper, but it will be very helpful in the future :D

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%2Ff++1%2F(sqrt(1+-+(c%2F(2+a+f))%5E2